# Notation for expressing generalization over two types of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I am working with sequences that have in their range two objects $a$ and $b$. In some cases, these sequences contain the two terms once each, $( a, b )$. In other cases, there are an undefined number of repetitions of each object, $( a_1,…, b_n )$. How could I express a generalization over these possibilities? I want to express that a sequence could be $( a, b )$ with length 2 or $( a_1,…, b_n )$ with undefined length. I have read several introductions to the topic, but have been unable to find an answer. Is there a notation for this?

Comment: Is the sequence all a's followed by all b's like $( a,…a, b,...b )$? Normally, different subscripts implies different values, so using subscripts seems a bit misleading unless different values is the intent.

Comment: Yes, all a's are followed by a's and likewise for b's. There is no mixing.